# Why do both sine and cosine have been used in positional encoding in the transformer model?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, transformer, machine-translation, positional-encoding

The Transformer model proposed in "Attention Is All You Need" uses sinusoid functions to do the positional encoding.

Why have both sine and cosine been used? And why do we need to separate the odd and even dimensions to use different sinusoid functions?